# Why I'm getting error while writing into text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, file-handling

This is my code____

```
file.write(symbol, " 5 Day's Average Sales%: ", gy)
```

I'm getting this error___

```
TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing three arguments into the write function.
symbol,
" 5 Day's Average Sales%: ",
gy

the write function only takes one string as a parameter
try using an F-string

```
file.write(f"{symbol} 5 Day's Average Sales%: {gy}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended:

```
print(symbol, "5 Day's Average Sales:", gy, file=file)
```

The `write` function takes a string.